# How to parse json array into list in dart?

Tags: json, dart

As for the script below, I have two different json for single record and multiple record as a list. I can parse the single data using the `Person` class. For the json with a list, I'm using ther `PersonList` class but I'm getting an error because the json key `result` is not needed anymore. Is there a way to parse the list without changing the `Person` class? Or should I not use the `PersonList` class and just create a `List<Person>`?

I saw this example but its only working if the json is a whole list like [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

```
var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(rawJsonMulti) as List;
    return jsonResponse.map((p) => Person.fromJson(p).toList();
```

Can you show me how to use  the above  script using my json. Thanks.

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {

  String rawJsonMulti = '{"result": [{"name":"Mary","age":30},{"name":"John","age":25}]}';
  String rawJsonSingle = '{"result": {"name":"Mary","age":30}}';
  
// Working for non list json  
//   final result = json.decode(rawJsonSingle);
//   var obj = Person.fromJson(result);
//   print(obj.name);

  
  final result = json.decode(rawJsonMulti);
  var obj = PersonList.fromJson(result);
  print(obj.listOfPerson[0].name);

}


  class PersonList {
  final List<Person> listOfPerson;

  PersonList({this.listOfPerson});

  factory PersonList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var personFromJson = json['result'] as List;

    List<Person> lst =
        personFromJson.map((i) => Person.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return PersonList(listOfPerson: lst);
  }
}


  class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    
    //will only work on result is not a list
    Person({this.name, this.age});
    factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return Person(name: json['result']['name'],
                   age: json['result']['age']);
    }

//  This will work on json with list but not in single
//  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
//       return Person(name: json['name'],
//                    age: json['age']);
//     }
    

  }
```

Comment: So you want the code to support both `rawJsonMulti` and `rawJsonSingle` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the `dynamic` to a `List<dynamic>` you can map each element in the jsonDecoded list.

Example:

````dart
import 'dart:convert';

final decodedJson = jsonDecode(rawJsonMulti) as List<dynamic>;
final personList = decodedJson
    .map((e) => Person.fromJson(
        e as Map<String, dynamic>))
    .toList();

return PersonList(listOfPerson: personList);
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try take a look at this solution where I have fixed your code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const rawJsonMulti =
      '{"result": [{"name":"Mary","age":30},{"name":"John","age":25}]}';
  const rawJsonSingle = '{"result": {"name":"Mary","age":30}}';

  final resultMulti = json.decode(rawJsonMulti) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final personListMulti = PersonList.fromJson(resultMulti);
  print(personListMulti.listOfPerson[0]); // Mary (age: 30)
  print(personListMulti.listOfPerson[1]); // John (age: 25)

  final resultSingle = json.decode(rawJsonSingle) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final personListSingle = PersonList.fromJson(resultMulti);
  print(personListSingle.listOfPerson[0]); // Mary (age: 30)
}

class PersonList {
  final List<Person> listOfPerson;

  PersonList({this.listOfPerson});

  factory PersonList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['result'] is List) {
      final personsFromJson = json['result'] as List;
      return PersonList(listOfPerson: [
        ...personsFromJson
            .cast<Map<String, Object>>()
            .map((i) => Person.fromJson(i))
      ]);
    } else {
      final personFromJson = json['result'] as Map<String, Object>;
      return PersonList(listOfPerson: [Person.fromJson(personFromJson)]);
    }
  }
}

class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person({this.name, this.age});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Person(name: json['name'] as String, age: json['age'] as int);
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '$name (age: $age)';
}
```